# gnuplot : handle tsv file with missing (empty) data

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot a tsv file with some data missing. I'm looking for a way to have gnuplot recognize empty data. As far as I've tried, gnuplot seems to handle line `a\t\tc` as `[a,c]`, but I want it to think of the data as `[a,empty,c]`.

I have a file, `data.tsv`, like this:

```
data1     data2     data3
1.2       12.4      129.3
2.4       32.4      134.8
3.2                 121.5
3.4       15.4      214.5
```

Please consider the data is separated with `\t`.  That is, the line 0 is "`data1\tdata2\tdata3\n`", the line 3 is '`3.2\t\t121.5\n`' . Note that in the line 3, the value for data2 is missing.

When I tell gnuplot

```
set datafile separator "\t"
plot "data.tsv" using 1:2
```

gnuplot plots the data, yes, but it uses the value for data3 on the line 3, resulting in plotting `[1.2, 2.4, 3.2, 3.4]` versus `[12.4, 32.4, 121.5, 15.4]`.

I would like to plot `[1.2, 2.4, 3.4]` versus `[12.4, 32.4, 15.4]`. At least, I don't want `121.5` getting into the plot. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is a bug in your gnuplot version (which one do you have?). Your minimal script

```
set datafile separator "\t"
plot "data.tsv" using 1:2
```

works fine for me on Linux since version 4.6.4. With 4.6.3 and previous versions I do also see your problem.

Comment: Sadly, I'm using version 4.4. I'm very happy to know upgrading fixes this problem. Thank you!

Comment: +1 for spotting the bug. @Yosh if you're stuck on an older version, please see my answer for a way to get around this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you're stuck on an older version of gnuplot and want to get round this problem, you could change the format of your data using awk:

```
$ awk -F'\t' -v OFS=',' '{$1=$1}1' data.tsv
1.2,12.4,129.3
2.4,32.4,134.8
3.2,,121.5
3.4,15.4,214.5
```

This short awk script converts tabs in the input to commas in the output. The `$1=$1` assignment is just a way of getting awk to touch the file. The `1` at the end always evaluates to true, so the line is printed.

You can use this directly in gnuplot:

```
set datafile separator ","                                   
plot "<awk -F'\t' -v OFS=',' '{$1=$1}1' data.tsv" using 1:2
```